# Foundation - Top Bar and Icon Bar in one template

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm working on `Foundation Zurb` template and I'm trying to get it working. 
I have `Top Bar` at the top of the screen *(full width)*, `Icon Bar` at the left side *(full height)*. I know that Foundation has 12 grid system.

According to Foundation:

> The Foundation Top Bar gives you a great way to display a complex
>   navigation bar on small, medium or large screens.

And:

> An Icon Bar provides a menu to quickly navigate an app. Use the Icon
>   Bar horizontally or vertically, with the labels below the icons or to
>   the right. Have it your way.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is my template. I've took out div.large-9.columns etc.. Because they were braking the view.

```
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
    <ul class="title-area">
      <li class="name">
        <h1><a href="#">LOGO PLACEHOLDER</a></h1>
      </li>
      <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
    </ul>

    <section class="top-bar-section">

      <!-- Right Nav Section -->
      <ul class="right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> Go PRO</a></li>
        <li class="has-dropdown">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> My Account</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>Some Li's here</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Left Nav Section -->
      <ul class="left">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-database"></i> ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i> TWO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> THREE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </nav>

  <!-- Left Nav Sidebar -->
  <div class="icon-bar vertical five-up">
    <a class="item">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
      <label>Home</label>
    </a>
    <a class="item">
      <i class="fa fa-gamepad"></i>
      <label>ONE</label>
    </a>
    <a class="item">
      <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
      <label>TWO</label>
    </a>
    <a class="item">
      <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
      <label>THREE</label>
    </a>
    <a class="item">
      <i class="fa fa-trophy"></i>
      <label>FOUR</label>
    </a>
  </div>
```

I want to achieve:

- **Top Bar** and **Icon Bar** the same
- **Content Area** to be fixed and have `large-8` or `large-9`
- **Sidebar** to be fixed and have `large-3`

What I've already tried:

- Was separating all 3 bits with `div.large-1/8/3`, nothing happened
- Was nesting them into `div.row`
- I think I've tried almost everything, but have no idea, what is the problem.

Comment: can u code in jsfiddle...  am not getting this point 1)Top Bar and Icon Bar the same

Comment: Sorry no, now I'm from mobile for a while, it will take ages to do that..

Comment: My code snippet is basically the header. If you will start adding div's with "small-X/large-X" the Left Icon Bar is going not height:100% anymore, and the these div blocks will start from the next line, but not in 1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had done the changes in html and css. this what your expecting

html code

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
    <ul class="title-area">
      <li class="name">
        <h1><a href="#">LOGO PLACEHOLDER</a></h1>
      </li>
      <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
    </ul>

    <section class="top-bar-section">

      <!-- Right Nav Section -->
      <ul class="right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> Go PRO</a></li>
        <li class="has-dropdown">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> My Account</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>Some Li's here</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Left Nav Section -->
      <ul class="left">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-database"></i> ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i> TWO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> THREE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </nav>

  <!-- Left Nav Sidebar -->

<div class="medium-1 columns left-nav">
  <div class="icon-bar vertical five-up">
    <a class="item">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
      <label>Home</label>
    </a>
    <a class="item">
      <i class="fa fa-gamepad"></i>
      <label>ONE</label>
    </a>
    <a class="item">
      <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
      <label>TWO</label>
    </a>
    <a class="item">
      <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
      <label>THREE</label>
    </a>
    <a class="item">
      <i class="fa fa-trophy"></i>
      <label>FOUR</label>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="medium-8 columns content-area">content-area</div>
<div class="medium-3 columns sidebar">columns sidebar</div>
```

css code

```
.columns.content-area{border:1px solid #111;padding:0}
.columns.sidebar{border:1px solid #111;padding:0}
.columns.left-nav{padding:0}
.icon-bar.vertical.five-up{width:100%}
```

[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/k18qe93r/1/)

Comment: Hi, it's almost what I've needed. The thing is that in changed the height on left Icon Bar and it doesn't have now full height block.

Comment: I've wrapped all 3 divs into 1 and added height:100% and it worked, not sure what's going to happen when I will add a dummy text and images.